# Javascript Websocket to listen on port 80

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I have a web server deployed in port `80` with Websocket running in its javascript.

```
var wsURL = ws://localhost:80/ws"
wsConn = new WebSocket(wsURL);
```

But I keep getting this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I had no problem when I run this locally with port other than `80` but in production I need to use port `80` and keep getting this error.

Is there anyway that I can make `WebSocket` work with port `80`?

Comment: try window.location.hostname instead of localhost

Comment: @Michael-R Worked! Thanks!

Comment: cool I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `window.location.hostname` will clear any URL discrepancies you have while in production. Using `localhost` in the url will result in ws requests to the user's local machines as opposed to your production server. Hence your connection refusal.

***Note*** This method is only meant for when a client is directly served by the same WebSocket server, if servers are ever different you would need a way to get the exact url of the WebSocket server. --Most likely some type of redirect/forward/proxy from the backend (serving the frontend) to the WebSocket server.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is initialized by an HTTP request , ws protocol is using port 80 by default.

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means you are not listening on this port, you need check your web server config or logs.

On Linux/OSX , You must start your program using root user to listen port < 1024 , you can use setuid() to drop root privilege after that.